# React reducer function save the original value

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-reducer

### this is the reducer function 1  ====> this holds the value that can change

```
export const initStateLineDetails = {
  loading: true,
  error: "",
  submit: true,
  update: false,
  rowcount: 0,
  data: []
};

export const lineDetailsReducer = (lineDetailsState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){        
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...lineDetailsState,
        loading: false,
        error: "",
        submit: action.submitState,
        update: action.updateState,
        rowcount: action.rowcount,
        data: action.payload
      }; 
    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...lineDetailsState,
        loading: false,
        submit: true,
        update: false,
        rowcount: 0,
        error: "Unable to fetch Line details.",
        data: []
      };
    case "update":
      return {
        ...lineDetailsState,
        data: action.payload
      };
        default:
            return lineDetailsState;
    }
}
 
const LineDetailsProvider = ({children}) => {


    const [ lineDetailsObjState, lineDetailsObjDispatch ] = useReducer(lineDetailsReducer, initStateLineDetails);
    return (
        <LineDetailsReduceContext.Provider value={{lineDetailsState: lineDetailsObjState, lineDetailsDispatch: lineDetailsObjDispatch}}>
            {children}
        </LineDetailsReduceContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default LineDetailsProvider;
```

### this is the reducer function 2 ====> this holds the initial value

```
export const initStateLineOriDetails = {
  val: []
};

export const lineOriDetailsReducer = (lineOriDetailsState, action) => {
   switch(action.type){    
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...lineOriDetailsState,
        val: action.payload
      }; 
    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...lineOriDetailsState,
        val: []
      };
      default:
         return lineOriDetailsState;
   }
}
 
const LineOriDetailsProvider = ({children}) => {


   const [ lineOriDetailsObjState, lineOriDetailsObjDispatch ] = useReducer(lineOriDetailsReducer, initStateLineOriDetails);
   return (
      <LineOriDetailsReduceContext.Provider value={{lineOriDetailsState: lineOriDetailsObjState, lineOriDetailsDispatch: lineOriDetailsObjDispatch}}>
         {children}
      </LineOriDetailsReduceContext.Provider>
   )
}
export default LineOriDetailsProvider;
```

In a separate component both these reducer functions are called

### when restore is clicked

```
let dummyObj = { ...alertOriLogsContext.lineOriDetailsState } 
alertLogsContext.lineDetailsDispatch({
   type: "update",
   payload: dummyObj['val'],
});
```

So now the reducer function 1 will have the original function
this works for the first time restore is clicked, but on the second attempt
the val in reducer function 2 is saved as the changed value/data of reducer function 1

Comment: you are dispatching `type: "update"`, I don't see where this action would go since your reducers only have switch cases for `"FETCH_SUCCESS"` and `"FETCH_FAILURE"`

Comment: Reducer can have any number of cases

Comment: That's not the point, I mean you don't have any `case: "update"` in your switch

Comment: it is there, after FETCH_FAILURE, reducer function 1

case "update":
      return {
        ...lineDetailsState,
        data: action.payload
      };